# The command "Get-WindowsCapability -Online" doesn't list all languages and components, how can I list all?

Tags: powershell

The command "Get-WindowsCapability -Online" gives a long list of languages and components that I can then install using "Add-WindowsCapability -Online" but it doesn't list all of them. For example if I go into Windows Settings > Time & Language > Language I can add there through the GUI English (Belize) and other languages which are not listed by "Get-WindowsCapability -Online".

How can I list or install the missing components using PowerShell? Thanks.